# What is Causing Power Issue with Blue Snowball?

Tags: microphone, usb

I recently got a Blue Snowball microphone, and it has been working great, though recently it will no longer work in most cases.

As indicated by the red light, the microphone does not receive power unless the USB cable is only partially inserted. Fully inserting the USB cable into the mic. simply results in no data or power connection (again according to the red indicator light).

This happens independently of the computer, operating system, or USB cable used. What could be causing this, or what can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a faulty microphone. You should return it and have it repaired or replaced under warranty.